# I can't post due to one closed question

Tags: support, closed-questions, post-ban

I registered on this site because I want to learn from the experienced programmers.
So I look many interesting questions and answer. Then I ask [my first question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/155183/58225), some days later this was closed as a duplicate. Also I make [an acceptable answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/155194/58225). After that I didn't very much but look at some Q&A.

Right now my account is banned. When I try to ask a question, I get this message:

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See
>   http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more.

My questions are:

- It is fine?
- How can I do to ask new questions?

---

What I can tell in my favor is that my incorrect questions was written a long time ago and now I have learned from [my Ubuntu account](https://askubuntu.com/users/62483/). I also make good things like create the pascal tag.

Comment: Have you read the link? It clearly explains what you need to do in order to be able to ask questions again. Also, your account has 4 questions asked - 3 of them have been deleted and all of those 3 have a net negative number of down votes.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Thanks. Yes, the link explains very well the reason but I thought that it would be good hear the user opinions.

Comment: +1: One question triggers a question ban? It doesn't make sense. // You should probably file a bug report.

Comment: Wait - @ChrisF said that you posted three other deleted questions. Is this true?

Answer (score 7):

You have three other questions that were down-voted, closed and deleted. These are also taken into account for the question block.

If you follow the instructions on the page linked to you can re-earn the right to post questions.

The main thing you need to do is to try to improve the quality of the question you just asked and also provide more high quality answers.

Answer (score 6):

> Then I ask my first question, some days later this was closed as a duplicate. Also I make an acceptable answer. After that I did nothing but look at some Q&A.

[image]

The question you linked to might be the first one you asked, but it's not the only one. The question ban is automatic, there is nothing anyone can do to help you reverse it, it's completely up to you. Read the instructions in the [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers/86998#86998) carefully (twice) and follow them to the letter.

You should also read and follow the advice given on:

- Matt Gemmell's excellent article [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), and
- Jon Skeet's [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) blog post, the canonical guide on asking questions on Stack Overflow (the principles apply on Programmers as well).

While your willingness to learn is admirable, you'll have to keep in mind that we are all freely volunteering our time here and expecting you to do some minimal research and to show us that you at least tried to solve your problem prior to asking is not unreasonable.

Comment: Thank you. I must say that I cannot see the three questions in red. In that way is more difficult to learn from my errors.

Comment: @Lucio They are deleted (that's why they are in red). All three of them are questions about implementation issues, and as such they are off topic on Programmers and should have been asked on Stack Overflow. I deleted two of them when I noticed you had already asked them on Stack Overflow, and one you deleted yourself. Please read the [Programmers FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq) carefully and don't post exactly the same question on multiple sites.

Comment: @Lucio Even if you don't know what the right site for your question is, it's better to post at the wrong one than post it on both. For more details on picking the right site see: [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)

Comment: Yes, your right. My problem was there I after do the question I noticed that was in the wrong place and (instead of wait to be able delete the post) I posted it in the other site, and then delete the first one.